# Posicionar div flotante, responsive

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid-layout

Estoy realizando esta vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He logrado hacer el resto pero la etiqueta que dice  $500 me esta costando. El problema es que tiene que ser responsive, entonces no puedo hacer un div flotante con position absolute. Alguna idea?

Mi ultima opcion seria añadir el div al lado de un div correspondiente a la informacion, pero esta opcion me haria mas espacio entre los elementos, lo cual hace que no se vea exactamente igual al mockup. Alguna idea de que puedo hacer?

Este es el codigo que tengo actualmente, estoy usando React, Material UI:

```
<Styled.Container>
        <p>carousel</p>
        <Styled.InfoContainer>
            <div>
                <label>Disponibilidad</label>
                <p><span><EventIcon /></span> 23 Julio - 25 Agosto</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Duracion</label>
                <p><span><QueryBuilderIcon /></span> {duration} days</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Visitas</label>
                <p><span><PlaceOutlinedIcon /></span> {places} places</p>
            </div>
            <Styled.PriceContainer>
                <p>$500</p>
            </Styled.PriceContainer>
        </Styled.InfoContainer>
        <Button>See Package</Button>
    </Styled.Container>
```

Este es el CSS:

```
export const Container = styled.div"
   border-radius: 10px;
    border: 0.3px solid #a2a2a2;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    max-width: 19rem;
    min-width: 17rem;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;

   button{
       width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
        background-color: #070058;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        border: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: all .5s ease;

        &:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #A1004E;
        }
   }

   label{
       font-weight: bold;
   }
   
"

export const InfoContainer = styled.div"
   padding-left: 1rem;
"

export const PriceContainer = styled.div"
width: 2rem;
float: right;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
height: 2rem;
justify-content: flex-end;
background-color: #A1004E;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
padding-right: 3rem;

p{
    width: 1rem;
}
"
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema hay con posiciones absolutas? Si es responsive, con las media queries a partir de X píxeles puedes hacer que deje de tener posición absoluta.
Si no quieres usar posiciones absolutas, puedes hacer un grid o flex que englobe duración y visitas en un lado, y el precio en el otro

Comment: Necesito un mejor ejemplo del error para entender que está mal.